# Issues while exporting pdf from webgrid in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, pdf-generation, webgrid

I was trying to export webgrid content as pdf. I am following same link provided in http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/205/exporting-the-razor-webgrid-to-pdf-using-itextsharp.
 But i am having issue with page `GeneratePdf.cshtml` .First of all whether this file is view or partial view?? I created it as partial view.But the blog posted they are using webmatrix database.open method and i am using Entity framework for generating data .So i would be replacing the

```
var data = db.Query(sql); with var data = Model;
```

but i am not finding a way to generate columns the line `var columns = Moldel.First().Columns`  doesn't work.Can any body suggest me a code to replace the one posted in that blog with Model, i mean the entity generated on